# Is it appropriate to get help finding the time complexity for an algorithm?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm writing an algorithm but am not sure if my assumptions for its complexity are accurate. I'd like to know if posting the python code with my own assessment would be appropriate.

I believe I'm looking at an approximately linear algorithm O(a log(n) + n) where a would be the alphabet size.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's on topic here, but [SO] or [programmers.SE] seems like the place for that sort of question (if it has a place anywhere on the network).

Comment: This sounds appropriate for the [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: [cs.SE] is the way to go. Possibly also [codereview.SE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, it would be appropriate to post here provided that you can sufficiently describe your algorithm without looking at source code.  This is something akin to "what is the complexity of Djikstra's algorithm?" Where you can, with relative ease, describe how the algorithm works without appealing to source code.

If your question is about the complexity of a specific implementation of the algorithm then I would suggest that it is not so appropriate for this site and one of the others (i.e. Computer Science) is likely more appropriate.  Since you mention specifically your Python code, this site (math stackexchange) is likely not the best place for it.